# Material UI - Chip Array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am writing some code for a ReactJS component to have an array of chips. I want each chip to be styled uniquely, so I set up a makeStyles class for each one. I was having trouble trying to figure out how to change the class for each tag. This is what I got so far:

```
    const classes = useStyles();
      const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([
        { key: 0, label: 'Heating' },
        { key: 1, label: 'Printing' },
        { key: 2, label: 'Resetting' },
        { key: 3, label: 'Idle' },
        { key: 4, label: 'Suspended' },
        { key: 5, label: 'Suspend in Progress' },
        { key: 6, label: 'Attention - Printer Connection Lost' },
        { key: 7, label: 'Attention - Filament Out' },
        { key: 8, label: 'Attention - Cooldown Failed' },
      ]);


      return (
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" alignItems="flex-start" className={classes.container}>
          {chipData.map((data) => {



            return (
            <div classes={classes.chipContainer}>
              <li key={data.key}>
                <Chip
                  label={data.label}
                  if (label === 'Heating') {
                    className={classes.heatingTag}
                  }

                />
              </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </Box>
      );
}
export default PrinterStatusTags
```

So within the chip element, I have an if statement that is used to assign a specific class based on the label. My plan was to have an if statement for each label, but I am getting the following error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

Any ideas how I can assign a class based on the chip?

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

I would 2 things:

1. Add a new `type` property for every chip.
2. Create a mapper from the type (in the 1st point) to the classes

```
const classesMapper = {
   first: classes.firstClass,
   second: classes.secondClass
   // ...
};

const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([
        { key: 0, label: 'Heating', type: 'first' },
        { key: 1, label: 'Printing', type: 'seocnd' },
      // ....
      ]);
```

After you have the mapping between every chip to its type. Just render it:

```
return (
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" alignItems="flex-start" className={classes.container}>
          {chipData.map((data) => {
            return (
            <div classes={classes.chipContainer}>
              <li key={data.key}>
                <Chip
                  label={data.label}
                  className={classesMapper[data.type]} />
              </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </Box>
      );
```

## Old Answer

You should write the code a little bit different:

1. Use className property and not the property class (nor classes)
2. Set the condition inside the className property. Please note that there are better ways to set the right class but for your case, that would be good enough.

This is the code as it should be:

```
   <div classeName={classes.chipContainer}>
      <li key={data.key}>
         <Chip label={data.label} className={ label ==== 'Heating' && classes.heatingTag}/>
      </li>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my issue is, i have 11 chips, and I have four styling groups, is there a better way I can code up each class?